# project classpath in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, project

I have a question about adding folder/jars/libraries to a project in eclipse.

Let's say i download a folder off the internet which has libraries, do I add it as a folder, external jar or a  class folder ?

Either way, I added it and it is now part of the libraries available, but I still get an error in my program saying the class is not available.

I then tried to modify $CLASSPATH to where the folders are sitting and I'm still getting errors.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Once you have downloaded all the required jars and added them to an Eclipse project you should not have any more errors. If you do then there is probably a jar missing or some other problem.

Comment: Can you post some details about the error you are getting ? And the jars that you have already added to fix the problem ?

Comment: im trying to post a picture but it wont let me ( I dt have above reputation 10 -_-)

Comment: it's a compilation error saying the class doesnt exist. I need a CVSReader class (which I downloaded already and added to my project via java build path etc)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload a snapshot to http://imgur.com/ and then post the link here (instead of directly using the upload facility from Stackoverflow ) ?

Comment: try pressing Ctrl + Shift + O ? That should add any missing imports ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding all the JARs , try pressing Ctrl + Shift + O (as in Orange). This should re-organize the Imports and try to add any missing ones.

For example, go to excelToText.java and press Ctrl + Shift + O  OR Click Source -> Organize Imports like so :

[image]

Then when you Save the file ( File -> Save) do you see the Errors disappear ?

See **[this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkOKLbX1qzY)** video to take a look at how this works.

Comment: @Nidale, Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the 'Tick' mark next to it like so : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 2):

Simply try the following (if your project is a web-application):

- Add your libraries (I presume jar files) to your `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder. What you can do is simply copy the jar (i.e. Ctrl+C) and then past into this Eclipse folder. In this manner, the library will automatically be added to the build-path.

Alternatively, you can follow any of the three-steps outlined in this example:
[http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)

I would personally try *Method-3* first (which is exactly what I mentioned in the comment provided below).

If this does not work, please try add more specifics to your question. For example, which library did you download (it might help to mention in case you’re missing something we don’t know about). Also, what exactly are the errors you are getting? If you cannot post an image, simply copy what the error is.

Comment: it just cannot find the class (which I added to my project)

Comment: Try follow these steps: (1) Right click on your project (i.e. “MB”), (2) Click Configure build-path; (3) Click Add External Jars; (4) Locate all required jars, for example opencsv-2.3.jar, and click add...

Comment: Please follow the instructions carefully, it should not add it there, unless there is some type of configuration error in your project. In that case, try create a new Java-project and see how it goes. But have a look again carefully, at each step of the instructions provided in the link I’ve given.